# Airflow State of this instance has been externally set to shutdown. Taking the poison pill

Tags: airflow

Some of the Airflow tasks are automatically getting shutdown.

I am using Airflow version 1.10.6 with Celery Executor. The Database is PostgreSQL and Broker is Redis. The airflow infrastructure is deployed on Azure.

Few tasks are getting shutdown after 15 hrs, few are getting stopped after 30 minutes. These are long-running tasks, I have set the execution_timeout to 100 hrs.

Any configuration that can prevent these tasks to be shutdown by Airflow ?

```
{local_task_job.py:167} WARNING - State of this instance has been externally set to shutdown. Taking the poison pill.
```

Comment: I am missing the question. Add more details.

Comment: I got the same issue here. Still don't know what is the root cause.

Comment: Still don't have the reason for the same, but what I noticed once I increased the computation power these instances became less. Also added retry mechanism to this so that these tasks are picked up again.